# Sending access is denied error using htaccess on apache for all files but a certain one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

I have a folder containing various .php files, and I want to prevent direct access to them, BUT to index.php.

This is what I got so far, and it appears working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /403.php/$1 [R=403]
</IfModule>
```

Is this the correct way to do it? Also note that 403.php doesn't actually exist among the files I have in the folder.

EDIT: to better clarify what I'm trying to do -- I have a folder (we can assume named "includes") containing an index.php file, and various other files which are included by index.php.

I don't want users / malicious bots / whoever to be able to directly access anything in "includes" other than index.php.

In case they reach anything else (regardless whether the file exists or not), I want to send to the browser a 403 - Access Denied HTTP response code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is to use the `F` flag, which simply returns a 403 forbidden and you can use `-` as the target which just means "do nothing and let the URI pass through unchanged":

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,F]
```

Or you can try combining the condition with the rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !index\.php$ - [L,F]
```

Comment: Thanks! Your rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,F]` is definitely the way to go, shorter and definitely more correct than what I had before.

Answer (score 1):

You can either create an error page. Actually, some control panels have an application that will allow their user to create an SSI-enabled 403 *(Forbidden)* page with *.shtml* file extension. In **cPanel** that app. is entitled with *"Error Pages"* which were found in the *"Advanced"* section, and the 403 page will be going to saved in *403.shtml* basename. If you didn't found such kind of app., you can manually create an SSI-enabled HTML file, only if your server is configured to allow this. If it's not possible, you can still use another extension.

So, the more correct way is to remap the existed error page, such like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*) /403.shtml
```

But anyway, what are you trying to do?